# How to rename column header using index numbering in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following data frame

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({ 'gene':["foo",
                            "lal",
                            "qux",
                            "woz"], 'cell1':[5,9,1,7], 'cell2':[12,90,13,87]})
df = df[["gene","cell1","cell2"]]
df
```

That looks like this:

```
  gene  cell1  cell2
0  foo      5     12
1  lal      9     90
2  qux      1     13
3  woz      7     87
```

What I want to do is to change the column name in 1st and 3rd column.
Resulting in:

```
    X  cell1   Y
  foo      5  12
  lal      9  90
  qux      1  13
  woz      7  87
```

How can I do that using `0` and `2` index numbering.

I can do this

```
df.columns = ["X","cell1","Y"]
```

But it doesn't use column index.

Answer (score 5):

Make a list from the columns, alter the list, then re-assign the list to the columns attribute:

```
>>> cols = list(df.columns)
>>> cols[0] = 'X'
>>> cols[2] = 'Y'
>>> df.columns = cols
```

Alternatively, a one-liner:

```
>>> df.rename(columns={'cell1': 'X', 'gene': 'Y'}, inplace=True)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
df.columns._data[0] = 'X'

df.columns._data[2] = 'Y'

>>> df
     X  cell1   Y
0  foo      5  12
1  lal      9  90
2  qux      1  13
3  woz      7  87
```

General note: when in doubt, look at a class's __dict__ variable:

```
>>> df.columns.__dict__
{'freq': None, '_cache': {'dtype': dtype('O'), 'is_all_dates': False, 'is_unique': True, 'inferred_t
ype': 'string', '_engine': <pandas.index.ObjectEngine object at 0x000000000882DC48>}, '_data': array
(['gene', 'cell1', 'cell2'], dtype=object), '_id': <object object at 0x00000000028F4720>, 'name': No
ne}
```

Comment: A name with a leading underscore usually means "hey, pretend I'm not here!". It's not part of the public API, so unless it's documented as being OK to use, it may disappear in the future and break code depending on it. Accessing such "private" attributes can sometimes be useful, but there's a way of doing this via the public API, so I don't think this is a case where it's warranted.